# while performing stopwords on dataset in python3 getting error in printing function

Tags: nlp, nltk, stop-words

I'm trying to remove stop words using `NLTK`. I have a syntax error in the fourth line, but the first three lines are working fine.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
   print [i for i in senten
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
sentence = "this is a foo bar sentence"
print [i for i in sentence.split() if i not in stop]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python3 it's probably due to missing parenthesis in `print`, i.e.

```
print([i for i in sentence.split() if i not in stop])
```